# Access Database Slow Finding Any Records Not Matching

Tags: ms-access

My Access Database is slow when finding non-matching records

```
SELECT
    RT3_Data_Query.Identifier, RT3_Data_Query.store, RT3_Data_Query.SOURCE,
    RT3_Data_Query.TRAN_CODE, RT3_Data_Query.AMOUNT,
    RT3_Data_Query.DB_CR_TYPE, RT3_Data_Query.status, 
    RT3_Data_Query.TRAN_DATE, RT3_Data_Query.ACCEPTED_DATE,
    RT3_Data_Query.RECONCILED_DATE
FROM
    RT3_Data_Query
    LEFT JOIN Debit_AO_Query ON RT3_Data_Query.[Identifier] = Debit_AO_Query.[Identifier]
WHERE
    (((Debit_AO_Query.Identifier) Is Null));
```

I'm doing a query of two queries I created. The last query is just to compare these two queries and show what is missing between them which is what i posted above. I'm matching an identifier between the two queries which looks like this `583005-01-20185804.33` which is a combination of store, date and amount.

Here is a link to the database:
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/15f912909fbe2ea0a5111e44b953d11a20190808195913/db9912

Comment: If you could provide advice, would really appreciate it

Comment: Please include the query as SQL and information on the involved tables and indexes. Nobody wants to download your database.

Comment: SELECT RT3_Data_Query.Identifier, RT3_Data_Query.store, RT3_Data_Query.SOURCE, RT3_Data_Query.TRAN_CODE, RT3_Data_Query.AMOUNT, RT3_Data_Query.DB_CR_TYPE, RT3_Data_Query.status, RT3_Data_Query.TRAN_DATE, RT3_Data_Query.ACCEPTED_DATE, RT3_Data_Query.RECONCILED_DATE
FROM RT3_Data_Query LEFT JOIN Debit_AO_Query ON RT3_Data_Query.[Identifier] = Debit_AO_Query.[Identifier]
WHERE (((Debit_AO_Query.Identifier) Is Null));

Comment: I'm doing a query of two queries I created. The last query is just to compare these two queries and show what is missing between them which is what i posted above

Comment: I'm matching an identifier between the two queries which looks like this 583005-01-20185804.33 which is a combination of store, date and amount

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you format your question a little better?  Newlines are helpful to help people read, and code should be in `codeblocks`.  See our [Markdown Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) guide!  Also, make sure you post updated info in the question itself by editing it, rather than posting in the comments.

Comment: @Cullub, you should first post the links to [tour] and [ask] (you know the [shorthand links](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)?)

Comment: You query looks good so far; however, its speed depends much on the two other queries it is based on.

Comment: @Access_Noobs: Please reduce the amount of data in example db and **always** deploy db's as zip (reduces size to one fifth!)

Answer (score 0):

The query is slow because you don't use [indexes](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-and-use-an-index-to-improve-performance-0a8e2aa6-735c-4c3a-9dda-38c6c4f1a0ce) on tables and join on concated fields (Identifier is Location & Date & Total)!

Each table needs a primary key or it is not a table! That should be an autonumber for the beginning!

Indexing:

- Add a field called id to each table, datatype autonumber and make it PK.
- Add a key for the fields compared in the join and the where clause (set all index properties (primary, unique, ignore) to no)!

for table RT3_Data (because it is huge create a copy first, then delete the data, or creating index will fail on`MaxLocksPerFile`):

- store
- AMOUNT
- TRAN_DATE

after that reimport data from copy with query:

```sql
INSERT INTO RT3_DATA
SELECT [Copy Of RT3_DATA].*
FROM [Copy Of RT3_DATA];
```

for table Debit_AO:

- Location
- Total
- Date  (should be renamed as Date() is a VBA-Function)

Now change the query`RT3_Data_Query Without Matching Debit_AO_Query`to:

```sql
SELECT RT3_Data.store
    ,RT3_Data.SOURCE
    ,RT3_Data.TRAN_CODE
    ,RT3_Data.AMOUNT
    ,RT3_Data.DB_CR_TYPE
    ,RT3_Data.STATUS
    ,RT3_Data.TRAN_DATE
    ,RT3_Data.ACCEPTED_DATE
    ,RT3_Data.RECONCILED_DATE
FROM RT3_Data
LEFT JOIN Debit_AO 
    ON RT3_Data.[store] = Debit_AO.[Location]
    AND RT3_Data.[AMOUNT] = Debit_AO.[Total]
    AND RT3_Data.[TRAN_DATE] = Debit_AO.[DATE]
WHERE (
        (
            Debit_AO.Location IS NULL
            AND Debit_AO.Total IS NULL
            AND Debit_AO.[Date] IS NULL
            )
        );
```

Now the query executes in less than 10 seconds and for sure there are more optimizations (e.g composite index).